# How to skip drag event to stop a feature being dragged

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, openstreetmap

I am  new to OpenLayers and I'm trying to drag markers and skip some markers from being dragged, I've tried **`dragFeature.deactivate();`** it will deactivate entire features.

Please check this code :

```
dragFeature = new OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature(vectorLayer, {
    autoActivate: true,
    onEnter: function (feature) {                 
        //  example assign : x=1;
        //  if(x==0){ continue draging of a feature }
        //  else{  stop a feature from being dragged }
    },
    onLeave: function (feature) {            

    },
    onStart: function (feature, pixel) {
    },        
    onComplete: function (feature, pixel) {
    }
});
map.addControl(dragFeature);
dragFeature.activate();
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check feature attributes and deactivate drag handler for some values:

```
drag.onStart = function(f,p) {
    if (f.attributes.draggable === false) {
        drag.handlers.drag.deactivate();
    }
}
```

### [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/_DR_/sLfB9/)

Comment: Thanks for the help, after deactivating handler when I mouse over to a fixed feature it shows a crosshair cursor, is there any way to avoid that, so that i can fix other events on that fixed feature.

Comment: You should override overFeature method of DragFeature control. I've updated my live demo. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is typo in your code.

```
dragFeature = new OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature(vectorLayer, {
    autoActivate: true,
    onEnter: function (feature) {                 
        //  example assign : x=1;
        //  if(x==0){ continue draging of a feature }
        //  else{  stop a feature from being dragged }
    },
    onLeave: function (feature) {            
},
onStart: function (feature, pixel) {
}**,**        
onComplete: function (feature, pixel) {
}
});
```

I am just pointing typo, there might be you already solved the problem. :)